# Connect Azure RDP, "The logon attempt failed"

Tags: azure, remote-desktop

I've just created two Windows VM's in Azure, one 2012 Datacenter and a 2008 R2 SP1 and i am not able to connect via remote desktop to either of them. Both machines are running under the same cloud service and the RDP ports are mapped to two distinct public ports. Every time i try to connect i get the error message "The logon attempt failed".

Using NMAP in a Linux VM i also have there, i was able to check that the port 3389 is OPEN in both machines. Also, the public RDP ports respond correctly (e.g. are open).

I tried to enter using two different Windows 7 client machines, also with no lock. MSTSC version is 6.3.9600.16415, in both machines. I've used both the .rdp file, downloaded from the "Connect" option in the windows azure dashboard and a brand new RDP connection created by me - same result.

I've tried also to upgrade the VM size from small (1 core, 1.5 GBRam) to medium (2 cores, 3.6 GBRam), restart, setup a new clean windows VM, with different credentials... nothing changed, same result.

The really odd thing is that i was able to connect, after several failed attempts, to one of the VM's, the 2012 one, but only one time - after that, no luck, always "The login attempt failed".

Comment: Additional info: I was able to logon via RDP just now, but it failed to connect again just after. This confirms that the credentials are 100% OK. Its still failinf to logon, and i have made no changes whatsoever, so i don't know how i was able to RDP that one time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why, but the solution is simple (works every time, at least for me): I was copy-pasting the passwords from a KeePass, as i use this to generate and maintain the huge amount of credentials i use one way or another.

SOLUTION: instead of copy-paste, type the password

The drawback is that i have to use simpler passwords for this access

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was changing the RDP login screen to use a different account, and use the "local account" which is the name of the VM and the username, like so:

`TheVMName\TheAdminUsername`

Where `TheVMName` is the name of your VM, and `TheAdminUserName` is the admin user name you used for that machine.
I was able to find/confirm the latter on the `Reset Password` screen under the `SUPPORT + TROUBLESHOOTING` section on the left.

Answer (score 4):

Since Windows 10, you need the domain is automatically set to MicrosoftAccount followed by your email address as username. MicrosoftAccount\My@UserName.com

Instead, the username is like UserName.com\My.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to login and failed using windows 8.1 Pro to an azure vm.  The message I got repeatedly was "Login Attempt Failed".  So my specific problem wasn't that i couldn't connect to the machine but that it couldn't authenticate...even though my my Administrator username and password were correct.

The way I logged into the machine was to provide the host name then the username:

Host\Username

My Azure account did not have a domain controller setup.

It was simply looking for it's local host machine name.

This link helped: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-log-on-windows-server/

Answer (score 2):

May be following can help:

1. In this screen please select the option "Use a different account":

[image]

2. Further type in "Domain\Username"

[image]

TIPS:

**- The "Domain" can be found on the "Overview" page for your VM in Azure. It's appearing as:
Public IP Address: [SomeIPValue].**

**- If you do not remember or have "Username" & "Password".The local admin "Username" & "Password" can be set to get access under:
   Azure -> Your VM page -> Support + Troubleshooting -> Reset Password.**

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem and it turned out that my password wasn't complex enough.
It was really confusing that Azure Portal even let me create a VM with such a password.

It was resolved by going to the `VM page` -> `Support + Troubleshooting` -> `Reset Password` and specifying a more complex password (both case letters, numbers, special characters and doesn't contain username).

Thanks to Jagjit Singh whose answer pointed me in the right direction. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

I found that, while creating VM, if we put password without any special characters, then it still accepts the password but the login to the VM will fail using that password. It gives an error "The logon attempt failed".

It may work after the "Reset password" option but sometimes it shows "Failed to reset password".

So better to put a proper password.

Comment: Same thing here, created VM with a simple password via Azure portal and was unable to connect via RDP. Resetting to proper password worked!

Answer (score 2):

Issue : "The logon attempt failed". ( Windows azure Machine)
[image]

I have tried multiple option didn't help, hence updating this as correct answer , it worked for me .

Solution :- While creating the password/updating for windows azure vm create the password as recommended by Azure with prescribed. Main issue with password .

Steps as below for Issue fix.

1. Once logged in Azure portal, click on VM windows machine , go to (Support and Troubleshoot)
   [image: From Azure Portal]
2. update the password as recommended by Azure as below
   (Password must have 3 of the following: 1 lower case character, 1 upper case character, 1 number, and 1 special character.)
   Password :- updated as 13 char which include 1 Capital, Lower Case and Special ,1 number .
   Password:- Azureuser@123

[image]

3. After updating the password as Microsoft Suggested it worked for me and able to connect windows machine as below
   [image]
4. Able to connect as below

[image]

Try about method it should work, if issue please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is too old, answering for new visitors.

Easy solution would be, you can try to **add new user or reset the password** from Azure Portal

This will add the user if it does not exist, and you can try logging in with new account.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We need to have strong password when we create user account for VM ..

It was annoying when I encountered this.I was only succeed when I reset my password step. Issue with portal allows is to create week password while creating VM and validation rules are different while RDP to using week password.Same validation rules applies when we re-setting password.