# Can't log in to Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have an Windows 8.1 VM on Azure that I've been successfully using for months. I login via the admin account that I originally set up.

Today my RDP sessions keep telling me that the password is incorrect.

So I used the Azure Portal to reset the password, but still can't get in. I've tried waiting for a while (in case updates were being installed) and I've restarted the machine.

I notice that the Portal UI says 'Provide a new user name for the built-in administrator account'. I've tried changing it with no luck.

Help?

Comment: Does your VM use a self-uploaded image, or a MSDN subscriber benefit image? This matters because resetting password require the installation of VM Agent. And, a self-uploaded image require to install it manually.

Comment: It's just one of the MSDN subscriber images

Answer (score 0):

Azure must have changed the username requirement.
It works if I login with host\username

[Connect Azure RDP, "The logon attempt failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774658/connect-azure-rdp-the-logon-attempt-failed)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: instead of copy-paste, type the password

This solution comes from teh answer of another similar question [Connect Azure RDP, “The logon attempt failed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774658/connect-azure-rdp-the-logon-attempt-failed?rq=1). You can have a try.